# Vaadin charts + Embedded Jetty + WebApp: run webApp using JAR

Tags: java, web-applications, executable-jar, vaadin7, embedded-jetty

I'm using vaadin charts in my webapp.
When I ran my application in IDE, its working fine but when I ran the same with jar it throws:

```
[/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.abc.xyz.widgetset.AppWidgetset/com.abc.xyz.widgetset.AppWidgetset.nocache.js] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

I used following command to build my app:

```
mvn compile assembly:single  -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dvaadin.charts.developer.license=<key> -Denvironment=dev  -Dversion=1.test  package  vaadin:update-widgetset install vaadin:update-widgetset install
```

I already set appwidgetset param in my webapp context:

```
setInitParameter("widgetset", "com.abc.xyz.widgetset.AppWidgetset");
```

My vaadin servlet is:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = true, ui = MyUI.class, widgetset="com.abc.xyz.widgetset.AppWidgetset")
public class CustomVaadinServlet extends VaadinServlet implements SessionInitListener, SessionDestroyListener {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
        getService().addSessionInitListener(this);
        getService().addSessionDestroyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroy(SessionDestroyEvent event) {
        logger.info("CustomVaadinServlet: sessionDestroy event called");
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event) throws ServiceException {
        logger.info("CustomVaadinServlet: sessionInit event called");
    }
}
```

My POM File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>xyz_app</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <vaadin.version>7.7.6</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>7.7.6</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.4.6.v20170531</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.version>5.0.0-ALPHA</junit.version>
        <jmockit.version>1.9</jmockit.version>
        <!-- If there are no local customisations, this can also be "fetch" or 
            "cdn" -->
        <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
        <spring.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.6.11</aspectj.version>
        <version.slf4j>1.7.5</version.slf4j>
        <shiro.version>1.3.2</shiro.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.maxschuster</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-autocompletetextfield</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GIT plugins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.mylyn.github</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.egit.github.core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Excel report generation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-excel-exporter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- PDF report generation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Vaadin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>grid-renderers-collection-addon</artifactId>
            <version>0.94</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-grid-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Shiro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>${shiro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>${shiro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-aspectj</artifactId>
            <version>${shiro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-guice</artifactId>
            <version>${shiro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${shiro.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Configuration needs that -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit5-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>${jmockit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Code covrage -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>emma</groupId>
            <artifactId>emma</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5320</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>emma</groupId> <artifactId>maven-emma-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>0.5</version> <type>plugin</type> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- apache commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>     
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- As we are doing "inplace" GWT compilation, ensure the widgetset -->
            <!-- directory is cleaned properly -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.abc.xyz.jetty.abcJettyServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.abc.xyz.jetty.abcJettyServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </webappDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </hostedWebapp>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
                    <soyc>false</soyc>
                    <widgetsetMode>local</widgetsetMode>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>                
            </plugin>

            <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by 
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/abc</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
            <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>

            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>



    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>nexus</name>
            <url><URL></url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

My embedded jetty main java class:

```
public void start() throws Exception {
        try {

            Server server = new Server(startPort);          
            JettyWebAppContext webContext = new JettyWebAppContext();
            webContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{
                    new WebXmlConfiguration(),
                    new AnnotationConfiguration()
            });

            webContext.setAttribute(AnnotationConfiguration.CLASS_INHERITANCE_MAP, createClassMap());
            webContext.setContextPath("/");
            webContext.setDescriptor(WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
            webContext.setResourceBase(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "src\\main\\webapp");
            webContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
            ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(new VaadinServlet());
            webContext.addServlet(sh, "/*");
            webContext.setInitParameter("ui", LoginUI.class.getCanonicalName());
            webContext.setInitParameter("widgetset", "com.abc.xyz.widgetset.AppWidgetset");
            server.setHandler(webContext);
            server.start();

            LOGGER.info("Jetty server started");
            LOGGER.debug("Jetty web server port: {}"+ startPort);
            LOGGER.debug("Port to stop Jetty with the 'stop' operation: {}"+ stopPort);

            Monitor monitor = new Monitor(stopPort, new Server[] { server });
            monitor.start();
            server.join();
            LOGGER.info("Jetty server exited");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799890/failed-to-load-widgetsets-in-maven-project-in-eclipse

Comment: @ŁukaszChorąży This is not duplicate issue.
pls refer updated question

Comment: What does your pom look like? We need to see how your app is being assembled...

Comment: @Morfic 
I updated the code